# How to fetch application icon and application description from iTunes store?

Tags: ios, app-store

How could I fetch application icon and application details from iTunes store if I have app id?

Comment: I edited my answer to provide much better information, specifically what you asked for.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I believe there is a way to retrieve at least some icons via one of the many **[App Store RSS feeds](http://www.apple.com/rss/)**, perhaps more easily **[via a custom feed](http://itunes.apple.com/rss/generator/)**. I've not tried this method, but I know that at least some apps and websites use them that way.

---

#### Better Answer

You can retrieve it all by requesting XML information from the App Store. Dan Grigsby wrote about it about a year ago:

**[App Store Data Mining Techniques Revealed – Part 1](http://mobileorchard.com/app-store-data-mining-techniques-revealed-part-1/)**

**[App Store Data Mining Techniques Revealed – Part 2: Scripting App Store XML Downloads](http://mobileorchard.com/app-store-data-mining-techniques-revealed-part-2-scripting-app-store-xml-downloads/)**

Part 2 explains how to send a query for a specific app using the app ID. The article doesn't provide code for doing it in iOS, but it's very straightforward once you know what to ask for.